# AWS ECR login command pipe in mac os

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am trying to login to docker & ecr in a single command in mac os.

So far I got till this :

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin Xxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

**Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request**

Any idea how to solve this?

```
aws ecr get-login --region ap-south-1
```

has the response, am trying to pipe that to next command

```
docker login -u AWS -p **KEY** https://xx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you're upgrading your AWS CLI to the latest version. Then, use the following command (replacing `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` with your actual account ID):

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | \
  docker login --username AWS --password-stdin AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

See also the [ECR docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html#cli-authenticate-registry).

Answer (score 1):

I was using wrong account id and the following helped me. First run:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

You should get an output that looks like this:

```
{
    "UserId": "AIDAUQ6COKW7R5SO7XYZ",
    "Account": "311256041234",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::311256041234:user/john" 
}
```

And use the account id, not "john" or the "UserId"(replace `your_region`):

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region your_region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 311256041234.dkr.ecr.your_region.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.

AWS Labs published an helper tool to ease the authentication against ECR.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not correctly match the region in the `aws ecr get-login-password` command with the region in the registry URL. In other words, I had:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

And it should be:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```